# The app won't work message while I could manually side load the universal apk

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app published on Google Play. I'm uploading aab file and using Google Signing.

Yesterday I noticed I'm getting "the app won't work" message on some of my test devices; while I could install the debug build. I tried downloading the universal apk from the Google Play dashboard and successfully sideloaded the apk on the same device.

Could anyone explain what's going on?